# apache add trailing slash redirects to different ServerName

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

In apache 2.2.22, I have multiple local servers setup such that localhostN refers to a server which I can access via local.myserver.com (for different "myserver"s). The problem is that one such server is doing a strange redirect when adding the automatic slash (I'm guessing via `mod_dir`), where accessing:

```
http://local.myserver.com/noslashdir
```

sends me to

```
http://localhost5/noslashdir/
```

instead of to

```
http://local.myserver.com/noslashdir/
```

I have not been able to override this behavior in the .htaccess file. Here are the relevant details:

/noslashdir/.htaccess:

```
DirectoryIndex index.html
```

/.htaccess:

```
SetEnvIf HTTPS on http_proto=s
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^noslashdir/(.*)$ /noslashdir/$1.html [L]

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^noslashdir/(.+)\.html$ http%{http_proto}://%{HTTP_HOST}/noslashdir/$1 [L,R=302]
```

/etc/httpd/httpd.conf

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.5>
    ServerName localhost5
    DocumentRoot /var/www/myserver.com/
    DirectoryIndex  index.php index.html index.htm index.shtml 
    <Directory "/var/www/myserver.com">
            Options Indexes +Includes FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
            Allow from all
            Order allow,deny
    </Directory>
    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "/var/www/myserver.com/cgi-bin/"
</VirtualHost>
```

/etc/hosts

```
127.0.0.5   local.myserver.com  localhost5
```

I have tried `RewriteRule`s, `DirectorySlash Off`, etc, but nothing has worked so far. All other desired redirects work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apache is using the `ServerName` you have set for your VirtualHost when creating “self-referential URLs”.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/mod/core.html#servername:

> “The `ServerName` directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating redirection URLs.”

You should set [UseCanonicalName](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/mod/core.html#usecanonicalname) to `Off`:

> “In many situations Apache must construct a self-referential URL -- that is, a URL that refers back to the same server. With `UseCanonicalName On` Apache will use the hostname and port specified in the `ServerName` directive to construct the canonical name for the server. This name is used in all self-referential URLs, […]
>   With `UseCanonicalName Off` Apache will form self-referential URLs using the hostname and port supplied by the client if any are supplied […]”

Comment: This looks like exactly what I need, but setting it in the httpd.conf file inside the VirtualHost section (and then restarting apache) did not work. Setting it in the main body of the file (and restarting apache) did not work either. What am I missing here?

Comment: According to docs, `UseCanonicalName Off` should be the default in any case. So if that doesn’t fix it, maybe the cause is something else after all. Can you temporarily remove your own RewriteRules, and see if the behavior persists?

Comment: ok, something strange is definitely going on.. I tried again, and now it works! This is very strange. I'm thinking there was some browser caching going on.. I was trying on firefox, chrome, and konqueror, and all were not working, and now all except chrome are working. Even with apache stopped, chrome insists on redirecting to localhost5. In any case, your solution solved it. THANKS!

Comment: In a day or two I will let you know how exactly I solved it, as of right now, I removed the main file entry of `UseCanonicalName Off`, left it as it was (with  `UseCanonicalName On`) and put it in the `VirtualHost` section. If it keeps working into tomorrow, I will know this was the ticket.